# Why does short pressing the left shift key switch the view mode in addition to increasing the throttle?

Tags: macos, kerbal-space-program

When flying a spaceship if I press left shift briefly and let go immediately it beeps<sup>1</sup> and switches the view mode<sup>2</sup> in addition increasing the throttle. If I long press it it just increases the throttle as expected.

Why does it take me into IVA view in addition to adjusting the throttle and how do I make it stop?

I thought it might have to do with Karabiner interfering with KSP but I disabled it and the issue still occurs.

I'm running OS X 10.11.3.

Here are the plugins I have installed in case they're relevant somehow:

- KerbalAlarmClock
- Docking Port Alignment Indicator
- KerbalEngineer
- EditorExtensions

<sup>1</sup>As in a "you can't do that right now" beep.

<sup>2</sup>i.e. if I was looking at my ship then it switches to IVA.

Comment: Did you check your keyboard settings to see if one is double-mapped to IVA and acceleration? Prob not due to the difference in how long you press, but it's worth checking.

Comment: The only values using LeftShift in settings.cfg are: THROTTLE_UP
{
 primary = LeftShift
 secondary = None
 group = 0
 modeMask = 1
 modeMaskSec = -1
} TRANSLATE_FWD
{
 primary = H
 secondary = LeftShift
 group = 0
 modeMask = -1
 modeMaskSec = 6
} EVA_Pack_up
{
 primary = LeftShift
 secondary = None
 group = 268435456
 modeMask = -1
 modeMaskSec = -1
} EVA_Run
{
 primary = LeftShift
 secondary = None
 group = 268435456
 modeMask = -1
 modeMaskSec = -1
} Editor_fineTweak
{
 primary = LeftShift
 secondary = None
 group = 0
 modeMask = -1
 modeMaskSec = -1
}

Comment: In particular these are the settings for toggling the view: CAMERA_MODE
{
 primary = C
 secondary = None
 group = 0
 modeMask = -1
 modeMaskSec = -1
}

Comment: Oh, "beep". Are you sure it is game issue, not system one? I do not recall KSP having beeps anywhere, it sounds more like "Sticky Keys" or other disability helper. ([it seems to work in OS-X in similar manner to Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18386?locale=en_US))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually tracked this down to the "Instant Send" functionality in LaunchBar which apparently uses shift as it's default hotkey. I suspect that it uses command-C to copy to the clipboard as part of its implementation which was causing the issue. I disabled this and everything is back to normal.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Seems like a very annoying situation.